# how to show html when using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating some elements through this code in JavaScript:

```
var tdiv = document.createElement("div");
tdiv.setAttribute('id', 'titlediv');
var ddiv = document.createElement("div");
ddiv.setAttribute('id', 'datediv');
var cdiv = document.createElement("div");
cdiv.setAttribute('id', 'contentdiv');
```

Now I have to append some html text to `cdiv`. I tried to do `cdiv.appendChild()` but it displays an error since it is not a node. Tried doing `var newsupdate_ = document.createTextNode(global[j].content)` then appending it but it looks like this:

[image]

Can I do setAttribute to place the content inside the desired div?

Comment: Can't you just use the `innerHTML` property?

Comment: @Icepickle nope since I have to load the data up for pagination first (I'm using an API that returns JSON data. I store the data into an array.) When I do innerHTML it returns with TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Can you show us how did you attempt to append those data?

Comment: I don't really see why you can't, as you seem to have the element (how else do you use the `setAttribute`)

Comment: The API returns HTML strings, which you're storing in some objects into `global` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) would not work in `cdiv` because there is no such method present in the element created by [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

[`createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) creates a new Text node. It will not evaluate any HTML present in the parameter string.

Try [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) like the following way:

```js
var cdiv = document.createElement("div");
cdiv.setAttribute('id', 'contentdiv');
cdiv.innerHTML = '<h1>Header 1</h1>';
document.getElementById('container').append(cdiv);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML, example 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";